# Gaussian Processes with noisy observations

Tags: machine-learning

In Gaussian Processes Regression, for noisy observations, noise are added to the diagnoal of covariance matrix (like the Equation 2.20: http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW2.pdf), or expressed with a Kronecker delta.

How to understand this assumption?

Comment: Should be asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/ I think

Comment: Not sure what you meant by "understand". I would say this assumption means the observations/measurements are noisy: what you observe is not exactly what it is.

Comment: I think j__ made a good point by thinking of two different types of kernels together. I think sometimes in practice, adding noise to the diagonal terms help make the covariance matrix positive-definite so that the matrix inverse is computationally stable.

Answer (score 2):

Good question!

One way of think of this is based on kernels and how to combine them. Kernels are the frameworks we use to describe how observations are related to one another, hence are used to build the kernel in the first place, and a good description of them is in Chapter 4 of the book you are reading.

[The Kernel Cookbook](http://mlg.eng.cam.ac.uk/duvenaud/cookbook/index.html) by David Duvenaud explains the effect of adding two kernels together via addition (he even gives pictures, yay!). Effectively when we add too kernels together we say that they both influence the relationships between observations but independently of one another. So we can ask what is adding a scalar multiplicand of the identity in terms of a kernel?

The answer - it says that each observation is completely independent of all others and there is a variance equal to the diagonal entries of the kernel, so in short each observation has i.i.d. gaussian noise associated with it!